# git repo in Dropbox, syncing on Linux and Windows, Whitespace issues

Tags: git, whitespace, dropbox, newline

I have a *git repo* in my Dropbox, that syncs between a Linux and a windows machine. I work on both machines on text files (`.cpp` on linux and win, `.tex`/`.txt` on win). So, my editors and programs both *write* CRLF (the win programs) and LF (the linux programs) files, all programs understand all variants on reading.

I would like to tell *git* to **correct** everything to `LF` (I like it that way best). On both platforms.

Alas with all my tries of `core.autocrlf`=`true/false/input` and `core.eol`=`lf` I get all kinds of messages. *"Will convert from LF to CRLF"*, "all files have changed" and so on. Currently I have

```
core.eol=lf
core.autocrlf=input
```

and I am on my windows machine.

When tomorrow everything is synced to my Linux machine, what will I see?

- Will there be LFs (as I currently have here)?
- Will I see that all files have changed?

I *hope* I finally understood everything, but I am really not sure. `input`? Sounds strange...

Answer (score 1):

It used to be that you had to have autocrlf set to true and that would do it. Currently, you should have it set to input. Then depending whether you are in linux or windows you set the eol setting differently.

To double check your settings a diff will show crlfs in the repository.

Also, edit the files with vim -b, this will show the line endings too.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Nope, doesn't work. I have `input` now set for 2 weeks (and thus now several Dropbox syncs later). Yesterday I committed everything on the Win machine (gits note was: "changing CRLF to LF"), and today on the Linux machine `git status` says everything (!) has changed. Or maybe thats ok, because it now has to change *everything* once to LF? hmmm...